# project lib depends on package. How to expose interface

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I have downloaded and compiled boost.
I have installed it in a designated directory and created appropriate BoostConfig.cmake file.

I have a lib project called lib1 which uses boost and finds it with find_package(...).

This is all very well and with the appropriate CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH boost is found and used.

lib1 uses boost by with:

```
include_directories(${boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
#no boost libs are used, thus no target_link_libraries(...)
```

The above all works.
Now I have a project called project1.
Project1 uses lib1 and includes it with:

```
add_subdirectory(lib1)
```

And links with:

```
target_link_libraries(project1 lib1)
```

compiling does however fail because project1 cannot find the boost headers included in lib1.

I see two immediate solutions to this:
1: Include boost headers1 explicitly in project1. 
2: Include boost headers in lib1 with include_directories(lib1 PUBLIC ${boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

I do not like solution 1 because I would like to just include lib1 and then let the system work out all dependencies in lib1

I do not like solution 2 because that effectively makes boost includes a part of the lib1 includes.

So what is the best/official way of achieving this package dependency of a subproject (lib1)?

Regards
Klaus

Comment: `I do not like solution 2 because that effectively makes boost includes a part of the lib1 includes.` - If `lib1` headers **use** classes or other definitions from Boost, then boost includes are *effectively* a part of `lib1` includes. There is no needs to hide this fact from library's users.

Comment: You should expose interface headers for lib1, which should not include boost headers. In other words, you should hide boost headers only in implementation part of your library and not expose boost dependency for higher level projects.

Comment: @SergeiNikulov You're absolutely right that it would be the most beautiful solution. It is however not always possible. I will consider if it can be done for my lib.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I agree. That is probably the way I will go.

Answer (score 0):

I went with "solution 2" for my project. Boost headers were included in the public interface of my lib so that users of that lib would not have to think about including boost headers themselves.